# list subdirectories in a directory only one level deep in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I know I can do this on one of my directories

```
$ find . -type d
```

but that will list all the sub-directories recursively. What can I append to list only the top-level subdirectories?

For example, if I have this directory structure

```
dir/dir1/subdir1
dir/dir2/subdir2
```

I do can this, but it does it recursively?

```
$ cd dir
$ find . type -d
dir1/subdir1
dir2/subdir2
```

I want this

```
$ cd dir
$ find . type -d <some option or pipe ?>
dir1
dir2
```

I know I can use `ls -d */` but I want one dir listed per line.

Thanks

Comment: Use `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d`

Comment: @anubhava, that's the option! Put this into an answer and I'll accept it.